Azure Data api builder + JWT setup locally not working
I'm using Data api builder for one of my databases locally. I've tried to setup JWT authentication, but i keep getting this error and i'm unable to get around it.
Error: Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
I've attached my dab-config.json, the server(JS file attached as txt as JS file upload isn't supported) which i'm using as issuer.
From the error i'm able to infer that the security keys aren't provided, but i'm unable to figure out any way to pass it. I've checked dab.draft.schema.json, and there's no key corresponding to it.
Please let me know if anything else is required.
Please help me fix this issue.
Here's my dab-config.json
{
    "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/download/v1.1.7/dab.draft.schema.json",
    "data-source": {
        "database-type": "postgresql",
        "connection-string": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=postgres;Password=;",
        "options": {}
    },
    "runtime": {
        "rest": {
            "enabled": true,
            "path": "/api",
            "request-body-strict": true
        },
        "graphql": {
            "enabled": true,
            "path": "/graphql",
            "allow-introspection": true
        },
        "host": {
            "cors": {
                "origins": [
                    "*"
                ],
                "allow-credentials": false
            },
            "authentication": {
                "provider": "jwt",
                "jwt": {
                    "audience": "my-api",
                    "issuer": "https://localhost:3000"
                }
            },
            "mode": "development"
        }
    },
    "entities": {
        "Address": {
            "source": {
                "object": "address",
                "type": "table"
            },
            "graphql": {
                "enabled": true,
                "type": {
                    "singular": "Address",
                    "plural": "Addresses"
                }
            },
            "rest": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "role": "authenticated",
                    "actions": [
                        "read"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


Here's my server.js i'm using for JWT(locally)
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const jose = require('node-jose');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const issuer = 'https://localhost:3000';
const audience = 'my-api';

// Load SSL certificates
const privateKeyPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key');
const certificatePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.crt');
const privateKeySsl = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath, 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(certificatePath, 'utf8');
const credentials = { key: privateKeySsl, cert: certificate };

// Load public and private keys
const privateKeyPem = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'private.key'), 'utf8');
const publicKeyPem = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public.key'), 'utf8');

// Create JWKS endpoint
async function getJwks() {
  const keyStore = jose.JWK.createKeyStore();
  await keyStore.add(publicKeyPem, 'pem');
  return keyStore.toJSON();
}

// Endpoint to authenticate user and issue JWT
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (username === 'user' && password === 'password') {
    const token = jwt.sign({  }, privateKeyPem, {
      expiresIn: '1h',
      algorithm: 'RS256',
      issuer,
      audience
    });
    res.json({ token });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' });
  }
});

// Middleware to validate JWT
const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('Authorization')?.split(' ')[1];

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, publicKeyPem, { algorithms: ['RS256'], issuer, audience }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(403);
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
};

// Protected route
app.get('/protected', authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'You are authorized', user: req.user });
});

// JWKS endpoint
app.get('/.well-known/jwks.json', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const jwks = await getJwks();
    res.json(jwks);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to generate JWKS' });
  }
});

// Start HTTPS server
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`JWT issuer listening at https://localhost:${port}`);
});


The login, and authentication(via protected route) is running perfectly.
Please let me know if i'm missing something or if anything else is required?
I've checked the documentation, explored the code base locally, and tried to troubleshoot things as well. Nothing seems to work, and i keep getting this error
      Failed to validate the token.
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(JsonWebToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.ValidateSignatureAndIssuerSecurityKey(JsonWebToken jsonWebToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.ValidateJWSAsync(JsonWebToken jsonWebToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)

Please note that i want to run all things on my local machine only. I do not want to use any remote server for anything.

To resolve the SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException error, you need to provide the public key to the Data API Builder configuration for validating the JWT token signature. This key should be made accessible to the API Builder so it can properly validate the JWTs issued by your local server.

@Rukmini - Thanks for your response. This is exactly what my question is. How to provide this key to the api builder?

If this was resolved, can you post the answer to help the next developer?

Here is a link to an issue I opened on the GitHub repo for this project, with the solution that fixed it for me.  https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/issues/2313
